# Billing and Shipping Address management in Symfony2 - Duplicate address in db if equal

Tags: symfony

I have a form customer registration type with an embed address form (billingAddress and an other optional ShippingAddress). 
If the user don't check the "different shipping Address" checkbox, I should have only one addrress in my db address table. Even so I get two differents addresses in my Address table (with the same informations). 
However, I check with "addAddress" if the address is already exist before add a new address. In fact in my Customer FormType, I copy billingAddress form data in shippingAdress form but in hasAdress method, $this->addresses->contains($address) return always false. I don't understand why...

Thanks

Here the code:

Customer Class

```
<?php

namespace DRMS\CustomerBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

use DRMS\AddressingBundle\Entity\Address;

/**
 * DRMS\CustomerBundle\Entity\Customer
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="DRMS\CustomerBundle\Repository\CustomerRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="customer", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="customer_id_UNIQUE", columns={"customer_id"})})
 */
class Customer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="customer_id")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $customerId;

    // Others attributes
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="DRMS\AddressingBundle\Entity\Address")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="billing_address_id", referencedColumnName="address_id")
     */
    protected $billingAddress;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="DRMS\AddressingBundle\Entity\Address")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="shipping_address_id", referencedColumnName="address_id")
     */        
    protected $shippingAddress;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DRMS\AddressingBundle\Entity\Address", mappedBy="customer", cascade={"remove", "persist"})
     ** ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="customer_id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $addresses;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->addresses = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of customerId.
     *
     * @param integer $customerId
     * @return \DRMS\CustomerBundle\Entity\Customer
     */
    public function setCustomerId($customerId)
    {
        $this->customerId = $customerId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of customerId.
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getCustomerId()
    {
        return $this->customerId;
    }

    // Others Getters/Setters
    // ...

     /**
     * Set billingAddress
     *
     * @param \DRMS\AddressingBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddress
     * @return Customer
     */
    public function setBillingAddress(Address $billingAddress = null)
    {
        $this->billingAddress = $billingAddress;
        if (null !== $billingAddress && !$this->hasAddress($billingAddress)) {
            $this->addAddress($billingAddress);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get billingAddress
     *
     * @return \DRMS\AddressingBundle\Entity\Address
     */
    public function getBillingAddress()
    {
        return $this->billingAddress;
    }

    /**
     * Set shippingAddress
     *
     * @param \DRMS\AddressingBundle\Entity\Address $shippingAddress
     * @return Customer
     */
    public function setShippingAddress(Address $shippingAddress = null)
    {
        $this->shippingAddress = $shippingAddress;
        if (null !== $shippingAddress && !$this->hasAddress($shippingAddress)) {
            $this->addAddress($shippingAddress);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shippingAddress
     *
     * @return \DRMS\AddressingBundle\Entity\Address
     */
    public function getShippingAddress()
    {
        return $this->shippingAddress;
    }

   /**
     * Add Address entity to collection (one to many).
     *
     * @param \DRMS\AddressingBundle\Entity\Address $address
     * @return \DRMS\CustomerBundle\Entity\Customer
     */
    public function addAddress(Address $address)
    {
        if (!$this->hasAddress($address)) {
            $this->addresses->add($address);
            $address->setCustomer($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove Address
     * 
     * @param \DRMS\AddressingBundle\Entity\Address $address
     * @return \DRMS\CustomerBundle\Entity\Customer
     */
    public function removeAddress(Address $address) {

        $this->addresses->removeElement($address);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Address entity collection (one to many).
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getAddresses()
    {
        return $this->addresses;
    }

    /**
     * Has address
     *
     * @param \DRMS\AddressingBundle\Entity\Address $address
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasAddress(Address $address)
    {
        return $this->addresses->contains($address);
    }

}
```

Address class

```
<?php

namespace DRMS\AddressingBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * DRMS\AddressingBundle\Entity\Address
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="DRMS\AddressingBundle\Repository\AddressRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="address"), uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="customer_adress_UNIQUE", columns={"customer_id","address_id"})}
 */
class Address
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $address_id;


    // Others attributes
    // ...


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="DRMS\CustomerBundle\Entity\Customer", inversedBy="addresses", cascade={"remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="customer_id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $customer;


    /**
     * Get the value of address_id.
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getAddressId()
    {
        return $this->address_id;
    }


    /**
     * Set customer
     *
     * @param \DRMS\CustomerBundle\Entity\Customer $customer
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setCustomer(\DRMS\CustomerBundle\Entity\Customer $customer)
    {
        $this->customer = $customer;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get customer
     *
     * @return \DRMS\CustomerBundle\Entity\Customer 
     */
    public function getCustomer()
    {
        return $this->customer;
    }
}
```

Customer FormType

```
<?php
# src\DRMS\CustomerBundle\Form\Type\CustomerType.php

namespace DRMS\CustomerBundle\Form\Type;

/**
 * Description of CustomerType
 *
 */

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents; 
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent; 


class CustomerType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) { 
                    $data = $event->getData(); 

                    if (!array_key_exists('differentShippingAddress', $data) || false === $data['differentShippingAddress']) { 
                        $data['shippingAddress'] = $data['billingAddress']; 

                        $event->setData($data); 
                    } 
                });

        $builder->add('customerName', null)
                ->add('customerFirstname', null)
                ->add('phone')
                ->add('mobilePhone')

                ->add('billingAddress', 'drms_address', array( 
                    'label' => 'drms.form.customer.billing_address',
                )) 
                ->add('differentShippingAddress', 'checkbox', array( 
                    'mapped'    => false,
                    'label'     => 'drms.form.customer.different_shipping_address',
                    'required'  => false,
                )) 
                ->add('shippingAddress', 'drms_address', array( 
                    'label' => 'drms.form.customer.shipping_address',
                )) 

                ;

    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     * 
     * If checkbox vatNumberOwner is checked, apply "vat_number_required" validation group for activate Vat Number test
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'DRMS\CustomerBundle\Entity\Customer',
            'validation_groups' => function(FormInterface $form) {
                $validation_groups = array('Registration');
                if($form->get('differentShippingAddress')->getData() == true) {
                    $validation_groups[] = 'ShippingAddressRequired';
                }
                return $validation_groups;
             },
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'drms_customer';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contains()` is implemented like this https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php#L189 That means you are doing a strict comparison on the object identity. Since the address object is created by the form and not managed by Doctrine in the identity map it will not compare to the objects created by Doctrine. Since custom collections are not supported i suggest you change the `in_array` logic to be not strict and put it in your entity directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Flip, I've solved my problem with a in_array comparaison and with strict option false    public function hasAddress(Address $address)  {    return in_array($address, $this->addresses->getValues(), false);  }